MouseEvents are not processed due to nested MouseWheelListener
I debugged one issue I have to solve and discovered what seems to be Swing's limitation
If your container receives a MouseEvent, it won't process it right away. Instead, it will try to delegate its processing to one of its children, recursively. The problem with that approach is a parent may delegate processing of clicks to a child that processes wheel motion only, and the click event will be ignored
Here are relevant snippets from the Swing library (the comments are mostly mine)
// java.awt.Container#getMouseEventTargetImpl

// comp is a child of "this", it happens inside a loop
                    if (comp instanceof Container) {
                        Container child = (Container) comp;
                        // recursive call on a container child
                        Component deeper = child.getMouseEventTarget(
                                x - child.x,
                                y - child.y,
                                includeSelf,
                                filter,
                                searchHeavyweightDescendants);
                        // if a child processing MouseEvents is found, it will be the event processor 
                        if (deeper != null) {
                            return deeper;
                        }
                    } else {
                        if (filter.accept(comp)) {
                            // there isn't a deeper target, but this component
                            // is a target
                            return comp;
                        }
                    }

// java.awt.Container.MouseEventTargetFilter

// this filter will return true when called on a MouseWheelListener
// even if the original event was about clicks

    static class MouseEventTargetFilter implements EventTargetFilter {
        static final EventTargetFilter FILTER = new MouseEventTargetFilter();

        private MouseEventTargetFilter() {}

        public boolean accept(final Component comp) {
            return (comp.eventMask & AWTEvent.MOUSE_MOTION_EVENT_MASK) != 0
                || (comp.eventMask & AWTEvent.MOUSE_EVENT_MASK) != 0
                || (comp.eventMask & AWTEvent.MOUSE_WHEEL_EVENT_MASK) != 0
                || comp.mouseListener != null
                || comp.mouseMotionListener != null
                || comp.mouseWheelListener != null;
        }
    }

I also wrote an MRE. No external dependencies are required
package demos.popup;

import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JPopupMenu;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Dimension;

/**
 * Right click to trigger a popup.
 */
public class PopupDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Container mainPanel = createMainPanel();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Popup Demo");
        frame.setContentPane(mainPanel);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private static JComponent createMainPanel() {
        JComponent mainComp = createPanelWithPopup();
        return mainComp;
    }

    private static JPanel createPanelWithPopup() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout()) {
            @Override
            public String toString() {
                return "Popup Panel";
            }
        };
//         uncomment this to "break" the popup
//        panel.add(createScrollPane());
        panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(250,150));
        panel.setComponentPopupMenu(createPopupMenu());
        return panel;
    }

    private static JScrollPane createScrollPane() {
        JScrollPane scroller = new JScrollPane();
        return scroller;
    }

    private static JPopupMenu createPopupMenu() {
        JPopupMenu popupMenu = new JPopupMenu();
        popupMenu.add(createTestMenuItem());
        return popupMenu;
    }

    private static JMenuItem createTestMenuItem() {
        JMenuItem menuItem = new JMenuItem("Test menu item");
        menuItem.addActionListener(e -> System.out.println("Test menu item triggered..."));
        return menuItem;
    }
}

I need to attach a popup to a panel that contains many (dynamic) JScrollPanes. Right clicks are "processed" by a scroll pane, de-facto ignored
How can I work around this problem?

Also add the popup menu to the component you add to the scrollpane.

@camickr the container that should have the popup contains many scroll panes, their number is dynamic. It would be madness to add the popup to each of those scroll panes one by one as well (so it seems to me, anyways)

@camickr ...also, they are contained inside another scroll pane. Simplifying, the panel has a scroll pane which, in turn, contains a dynamic number of smaller scroll panes. So it's complicated

This question is similar to: Passing events to parent. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I created a separate follow-up on the issue of passing popup triggers more than one level up

Calling scroller.setInheritsPopupMenu(true) should fix it:
    private static JScrollPane createScrollPane() {
        JScrollPane scroller = new JScrollPane();
        scroller.setInheritsPopupMenu(true);
        return scroller;
    }

The JScrollPane will still consume the MouseEvent, but now it will look at its parents when anyone consults scroller.getComponentPopupMenu().

Thank you! That seems to work. But what if it was about some other clicks, not popup triggers?

Hmm. I'm not sure. I'm having a hard time imagining the use case where I want to click a JScrollPane but let the JPanel parent process the MOUSE_PRESSED event. But if I had to: I might start by calling Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().addAWTEventListener(..); to intercept really high-level events and inject some custom logic about retargeting the MouseEvent elsewhere. Do you have a specific need/usage in mind?

Forgive me for not answering your question. I noticed something. inheritsPopupMenu works only one composition level up. So if a component's parent doesn't have a popup, but the grandparent does, getComponentPopupMenu() will still return null, even with the property set to true. Considering we have a complex composition hierarchy, it's a nuisance

I created a separate follow-up on that
